# Limit the number of test cases to be executed in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

A little background

- I am executing my test cases with Jenkins, I am doing a little POC with Jenkins right now.
- And, in my case, there are 500+ test cases which takes an hour to execute.
- I want only one test case to be executed just to know I didn't make any mistakes while doing my Jenkins POC.

Is there a way to limit number of test case to be executed ? something like..

```
  pytest -vv --limit 1
```

or

using conftest.py?

Comment: [The pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests), or just executing `pytest --help` contains all the information you are looking for. You're probably interested in the flags `--last-failed` (or `--lf`) or `-k EXPRESSION`, where EXPRESSION is a substring of the test(s) you want to run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can limit the amount of tests in many ways. For example, you can execute a single test by passing its full name as parameter:

```
$ pytest tests/test_spam.py::TestEggs::test_bacon
```

will run only the test method `test_bacon` in class `TestEggs` in module `tests/test_spam.py`.

If you don't know the exact test name, you can find it out by executing

```
$ pytest --collect-only -q
```

You can combine both commands to execute a limited amount of tests:

```
$ pytest -q --collect-only 2>&1 | head -n N | xargs pytest -sv
```

will execute first `N` collected tests.

You can also implement the `--limit` argument yourself if you want to. Example:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--limit', action='store', default=-1, type=int, help='tests limit')


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    limit = config.getoption('--limit')
    if limit >= 0:
        items[:] = items[:limit]
```

Now the above command becomes equal to

```
$ pytest --limit N
```